# In Excel VBA, how to access subs stored in an installed Add-In?

Tags: excel, vba

I have create an Excel Add-In. In that add-in are some modules and let's say module1 is one them. In module1 I have a sub declared as public sub abc() end sub

In my workbook I want to be able to use the function abc defined in the add in. It doesn't seem to work!

E.g. I install the Addin so that now it appears in the VBAProject sections. I create a sub in my main workbook (this is not the add-in workbook) and have a sub called def says

```
sub def()
  call abc
end sub



sub def1()
  call module1.abc
end sub
```

Neither of these work. Please help.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?  Is there an error message?

Comment: Just won't run the code. If you go to "Compile" project and it says the code won't even compile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to make sure the Add-in has a project name, then reference it through the Tools > References dialog.  See [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20191022132719/http://fontstuff.com/vba/vbatut08.htm) for more details.

Comment: The link no longer works.