# Call Add-In from a workbook macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to call a add-in from a workbook macro but nothing im trying is working. TTC_SendToEmail is the macro im trying to call and the add-in is called PersonalMacros.

I get Argument Not Optional when i try run this

```
Sub Test()

Dim r As Range
    Set r = Selection
        ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(629.5, 5.5, 79, 22.5).Select
        With Selection
            .OnAction = Application.Run("PersonalMacros", TTC_SendToEmail)
            .Characters.Text = "Send Emails"
        End With
    r.Select
End Sub
```

Comment: You need something like `Application.Run("PersonalMacros.TTC_SendToEmail")`. `"PersonalMacros"` is not the name of a macro and `TTC_SendToEmail` is not an input to it.

Comment: Thank you, I tried that and it says "PersonalMacros is not available in this workbook. This addon loads each time i open a book. Not sure why its not calling that macro in the addon

Comment: You might need to add a reference to it (Tools>References). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4066171/4996248). That answer applies to code in an actual add-in. Are you sure that the code is in an add-in and not simply in a workbook that is in the `XLSTART` folder?

Comment: Is there an open workbook named "PersonalMacros.xlsm" (or similar)?  In that case you'd need `Application.Run "'PersonalMacros.xlsm'!TTC_SendToEmail"`  See: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win001.htm

Comment: Yup there is code in the addon, and it's not a workbook in the startup folder. Was thinking of the reference thing but each day the sheet will change and the reference needs to be on the sheet and to do all that work daily won't work. I am hoping to do this other than reference